# How to make my query working (query on multiple tables)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to do the following query in **MySQL**:

```
SELECT DINSTINCT cstc.car_id FROM cars
    JOIN customer_cars cstc ON cstc.age =  student_cars.age
```

Where:

`cars` table has columns: `car_id`, `name`,...

`customer_cars` table has columns: `car_id`, `age`

`student_cars` table has columns: `car_id`, `age`

I know the query syntax is wrong because the `student_cars` table can not be recognized in this query (MySQL raise error).

(Basically, I would like to use the query to find out all car ids where **customer_cars** age equal to **student_cars** age)

So, how can I modify the query to make it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got you right, then that's it (unverified):

```
select distinct c.car_id 
from cars c
inner join customer_cars cc on c.car_id = cc.car_id
inner join student_cars sc on c.car_id = sc.car_id
where cc.age = sc.age
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.car_id 
FROM customer_cars c
JOIN student_cars s ON c.car_id = s.car_id and c.age = s.age
```